# Forcing a fullscreen game to run windowed?

Tags: xorg, opensuse, games

I'm having some issues with fullscreen games ruining my display and forcing me to reboot.

I'm wondering if there's a way to trick the game into thinking its going in fullscreen, when really I've restricted it to a window. Is this possible?

Here is the output of `ldd`:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
libvorbisfile.so.3 => /usr/lib/libvorbisfile.so.3 (0xf76d7000)
libfltk.so.1.1 => not found
libSDL-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0 (0xf7636000)
libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 => not found
libSDL_image-1.2.so.0 => not found
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0xf75ce000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0xf755a000)
libCg.so => not found
libCgGL.so => not found
libopenal.so.0 => not found
libalut.so.0 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf746a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf7440000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7422000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf72b4000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7299000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0 (0xf726e000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/libogg.so.0 (0xf7266000)
libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/libasound.so.2 (0xf7181000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf717c000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0xf703e000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0xf702c000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf7028000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf7022000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf701c000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0xf700e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf770c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf7004000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6fe4000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0xf6fe0000)
```

Comment: What's the game, or what display library does it use?

Comment: No clue about the display library, how would I find that out? And several games like Penumbra and UT.

Comment: `ldd /path/to/game/binary` would give a hint.

Comment: @Gilles, edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess but could using something like [`xnest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xnest) or [`xephyr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr) work, i.e., letting the game use the entire screen *which is not really the entire screen*?

Comment: I'm looking into these things, which seem really awesome. I've never used anything like this so it might take a bit for me to find my bearings. So this is like opening a whole new display for the same exact session as the one you're currently in?

Comment: I'm not quite fluent with them; but from what I understand, both approaches get you *a new X server (and session)* running in a window of the present one, yes. There's a [`xephyr` fork with GL acceleration](http://gitorious.org/xephyr-with-gl-acceleration/xephyr-with-gl-acceleration), too, but I'm not sure if it's actually a usable approach to your problem.

Comment: I've got them both up and running and I have no doubt this will fix my problem (and it's friggin awesome!). However, I can't seem to get my new session to grab keyboard input.

Comment: Using `xephyr`, `Ctrl+Shift` [is supposed to grab mouse and keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/280375/how-to-change-default-behavior-of-xephyr-for-capturing-and-releasing-keyboard-mo) - does that work?

Comment: Sir, you are a genius. I would upvote this answer more if I could.

Comment: Heh, most certainly not but you're welcome. `:)`